# Is there a better way to extract variable labels from a .dta in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set in .dta form and I'm importing into R using `heaven` package. I want to create a new data frame that contains each variable and its Stata label. Currently I've been doing this with the following code:

```
library(haven)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

dta_dt <-
  read_dta("stata_data.dta") %>%
  data.table

l <- lapply(dta_dt[0], function(x) {
  return(attr(x, "label"))
})

dt <- data.table(matrix(c(names(l), as.character(l)), nrow = length(l), byrow = F)) 
# as.character is necesarry in case there are NULL values

names(dt) <- c("variable", "label")
```

but this seems like a long, protracted operation and was wondering if there is simpler, shorter and/or more efficient way to do this.
Thanks

Comment: R's indexing is 1-based, so your use of `dta_dt[0]` confuses me a little. Are you intentionally iterating over the columns themselves with zero data in them? (`dta_dt[0]` should return a 0-row, `n`-column `data.table` here.)

Comment: Please check the `labelled` package which has great functions to extract or set variable and value labels.

Comment: @r2evans. Correct this is intended the command only needs the column names not the values so `dta_dt[0]` is enough.

Comment: @deschen. thanks! I will